# How to restrict htaccess to one domain and not all domains hosted?

Tags: .htaccess

I have htaccess on my shared hosting, with 2 domains. The current code is intent to rewrite all URL requests to https, but I need this to work only on one domain, whereas in the current code it is affecting both domains. How do I edit the code?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !promotion
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are the website root folders same for both sites or different?

Comment: well, its a structure which the cpanel inforces. public_html is the root for both, and inside it there is the directory of the add-on domain.  but the htaccess need to disregard this dir.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your htaccess and replace excluded-folder with the name of the add on domain directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded-folder/.*$
```

Comment: thanks but it didnt work :-(   i have tried to add the line   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/site.com/.*$   and it just disregard it.  is their a specific place i should put it?  10x

Comment: Create a new Htaccess in the sub domain directory and add this rule <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine Off </IfModule> and see if it works

Comment: nope. make things even worse.  i get 404 :-(   actualy the main htaccess transforms the add-on doamin www.example.com to https://example.com/example.com/